# Excel: searching for a maximum lower than X

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, sorting

From the sorted list of values, I'm looking for a maximum that is lower than X

Example:

```
  A  B  C
1 1     X=7
2 3
3 5
4 8   ANS=5
```

Do you have any smart ideas for this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can use VBa to do this, but not sure if VBa is something you want since you specified worksheet-function? The concept is, take all numbers into an array, sort ascending, filter for results only below the number and take the last item from the array.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use VBA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(A1:A4<C1, A1:A4, 0))}
```

Comment: Of course this assumes that `C1` is non-negative.

Comment: @Scott, Good point, do you have anything that will work for negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that the solution is actually so trivial!

```
=LOOKUP(C1;A1:A4)
```

Comment: hmmm.... got a vote down - is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Maybe because you asked for "max but less than", and lookup will give you "max less than or equal".  You should use array formula `{=MAX(IF(A1:A4<C1, A1:A4, 0))}`. Use ctrl+shift+enter to tell excel you've entered an array formula.  ps, down vote wasn't me.

Comment: @Jon good remark. Could you please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @DaveRook never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work for positive or negative values of C1.

```
{=IF(C1>=0,MAX(IF((A1:A4)<C1,A1:A4)),MAX(IF(-1*(A1:A4)>ABS(C1),A1:A4)))}
```